# Filter in Map Performance Tuning

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 (two) log files consisting of same information with similar structure (think Log B as a 'backup').

```
Log A: branchId, createdAt, value, subBranchId, etc..
Log B: branchId, createdAt, value
```

Now `A.value` is missing and I want to replace it with `B.value`.

Here's my attempt to do it. It run well on my localhost with small data but took forever when run in production.

```
JavaRDD<String> logA = sc.textFile(oldFilePath).cache();
JavaRDD<String> logB = sc.textFile(newFilePath).cache();

mappedLogB = logB.map(new Function<String, LogB>() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4815459211285505398L;

  public LogB call(String s) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(s, LogB.class);
  }
}).cache();

JavaRDD<String> revisedLogA = logA.map(new Function<String, String>() {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6211649129122188980L;

  public String call(String s) {

    String[] splitted = s.split("\t");
    String branchId = splitted[0];
    String createdAt = splitted[1];
    String value = splitted[2];

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
      JavaRDD<LogB> filtered = mappedLogB.filter(new FilteredLogB(branchId, createdAt));
      if (filtered.count() == 1) {
        splitted[2] = filtered.first().getValue();
      }
    }

    return StringHelper.toTabSeparatedString(Arrays.asList(splitted));
  }
});

revisedLogA.saveAsTextFile(saveOldFilePath);
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to optimize it? I think `mappedLogB.filter` is inefficient but until now I don't know any other way to get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, for each entry in log A where you're missing the value, you go through the whole log B. This can obviously get very slow if log B is of decent size or there are a lot of missing values in A. I'd suggest you first find the values from log A where the value is missing, transform logs A and B into pair RDDs with key (branchId, createdAt) and then simply do a join. This way you get a pair RDD with (branchId, createdAt) as the key and (logBvalue, logAvalue, subBranchId, ...) as the value. After that, you can simply map each pair into a string using the logBvalue.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try to use your idea.